# Debugging VSTO Word Add-in Does not allow me to break on certain events

Tags: .net, debugging, vsto

I am able to correctly break on some events such as Me.startup but other events like Application.DocumentOpen I cannot debug. I used AddinSpy to get some more information and it says I'Add-in DLL Path is not found.'

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What code exactly do you use for subscribing to the events?

Comment: Private Sub Application_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.DocumentBeforeSave